# Canvas app signed request 'content type' header is always using 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Can this be set to application/json?

Tags: canvas, canvas-app

We have a situation where our APIs do not accept a content type of 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and I can't figure out how to force the canvas app configuration to use another content type that works when I make a signedrequest post?